# An explicit expression for a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

I know that the open unitary ball $B^n$ of $\mathbb R^n$ are diffeomorphic and I also know some explicit forms of a diffeomorphism, many can be found on this very website. Now I would like to find a more refined diffeomorphism with some additional properties. Let $R>r>0$. Can we find a diffeomorphism $B_R^n(0)\to \mathbb R^n$ which restricts to the identity on $B^n_r(0)$?

Comment: Have you tried using bump functions?

Comment: @TedShifrin If I understand correctly what you mean, I still would have problems to show that the final function is a diffeomorphism. If I take a diffeo $\phi: B_R(0) \to \mathbb R^n$, I could choose two bump functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f \equiv 1$ on $B_r(0)$ and $g\equiv 1$ on $B_R(0)$ and they vanish outside or inside respectively an intermediate open ball $B_s(0)$ with $R>s>r>0$, but then? A natural candidate seems to be the function $g\phi + 1_{B_r(0)}f$, but why should this work? Maybe if we assume that $f+g=1$ everywhere things may go better -- but can we assume this safely?

Comment: Well, maybe I should have said ramp function. How about a smooth function that goes from $0$ (on some closed interval) to $1$ (on, say, $[R,\infty)$)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Still I see no reason why the function we obtain should be a diffeomorphism

Comment: You have gotten very quiet. If you are satisfied with the answer, you should accept it. If not, ask something more!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a smooth, monotone function $\psi\colon [0,R)\to\Bbb R$ with
$$\psi(u) = \begin{cases} 0, & 0\le u\le r \\ 1, & \frac12(r+R)\le u < R \end{cases}\ .$$
The construction is standard when creating partitions of unity, for example.

Define your diffeomorphism $F\colon B_R(0)\to\Bbb R^n$ by
$$F(x)= \left(1+\frac{\psi(\|x\|)}{\sqrt{R-\|x\|}}\right) x.$$
You can modify this idea in any number of ways according to your own aesthetics. :)